# How exactly are hidraw 'Billboard' devices interrogated?

Tags: linux, attacks, hardware, usb, badusb

I have some USBHub ( Ethernet + HDMI + USB + VGA). When it doesn't have anything connected it exposes to Linux operating system device:
'hiddev0, hidraw1'
in opposite to HID mouse:
which is visible as 'input,hidraw0'
Here are some log snippets from virtual machine but on barebone hardware it's handled exactly same way.

> [    3.098957] hid-generic 0003:0E0F:0003.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VMware VMware Virtual USB Mouse] on usb-0000:0b:00.0-1/input0

> [  332.312763] hid-generic 0003:14B0:0106.0002: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [StarTech.com Ltd. Billboard Device] on usb-0000:0b:00.0-2/input1

Bearing in mind BadUSB threat I'm wondering if:

1. The device is visible as hiddev0 while original mouse as input, from the other side it says input in 'usb-0000:0b:00.0-2/input1'. Would it be able to sent keystrokes to my operating system interface ?
2. I'm aware there are hid-quirks in linux kernel ( https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c ) but how to find what exact role the operating system assumed for this specific device ?  what's about Windows and Mac?
3. I've read that Billboard device are sometimes used to exchange metadata about other USB devices to avoid installing drivers, does it  mean that some userspace program communicates with it or operating system always handles it as above ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Basically, only Phison microcontrollers are vulnerable to BadUSB so I doubt your worries are justified..

Comment: I doubt you can be sure about this unless you're familiar with architecture of specific silicon die. PoC was provided for Phision but you can never be sure about others. Nevertheless the BadUSB is added just for context of this question,  my question is related to understanding what exactly and via which software components is exchanged between BIllboard device and host computer

Comment: I've found this https://www.usb.org/document-library/billboard-device-class-spec-revision-122-and-adopters-agreement but wondering about actual implementation on all 3 common operating systems